# Fancybox3 BeforeLoad changing URL doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm having massive problems getting Fancybox BeforeLoad to work.  Basically all I want to do is dynamically change the URL.  In my code below, I even have an alert popup showing me that the url is changing but when Fancybox is loaded it loads the original URL no matter what I do.  It's absolutely driving me crazy and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  I have literally run this on my web server and it does not work.

Assuming for a second that some of you can go and put this in JSFiddle and make it work can anyone think what might stop it working in a different environment?

HTML

```
<a href='test.html' id="mylink">Test Me</a></code></pre>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() { 
    $("a").fancybox({
        modal: true,
        type: "iframe",
        beforeLoad: function() { 
            this.href = "http://www.jquery.com"
        }
    }); 
});
```

This should load jquery.com in the popup - but doesn't.

I'm hoping someone else has gone through this pain because as far as I can tell this should work.  I've tried putting the URL into a variable and that doesn't work either.

No errors in the Browser console.  Nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned in the comment what version are you using, the title says "fancyBox3", but you are using a syntax of v2. This is how your snippet can be updated:

```
$("a").fancybox({
  modal: true,
  type: "iframe",
  beforeLoad: function(instance, current) { 
    current.src = "http://www.jquery.com"
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvWPBj?editors=1010

btw, you can get the same result simply by using the data attributes, example:

```
<a href='test.html' data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="https://blog.codepen.io/" id="mylink">Test Me</a></code></pre>
```

Comment: It's Fancybox 3.1.20 with jQuery 3.3.1.  I couldn't find any documentation that refers to the syntax you have provided.  Will give it a go ASAP.  Thanks heaps.